# How do I restore form state while going back in UIWebView history at iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiwebview

Lets pretend I have two HTML pages, **index.html** and **detail.html**. index.html contains **list of checkboxes** and a url link to detail.html.

**I expect:**

When I check some random checkboxes and then TAP on link to detail.html and then going back to index.html using triggered `javascript:window.history.back(-1)`. I expect to **find checkboxes in exact state when I left the index.html page**. It works this way in iOS Safari but no in `UIWebView`.

**Actual state:**

It show page in default state. No form history is preserved.

*I guess I have to do something to preserve this behavior but I didn't find any clue. The only semi answer I've found is to use hash tags in URL and restore checkboxes with javascript but I found this solution quite harsh.*

Thank you very much in advance for your time and every clue.